# How to match metadata with a nested file?

Tags: harp

My `_layout.jade` file

```
(...)
if toc
    div(id='toc', class="")
(...)
```

makes use of a variable set in `_data.json`:

```
{
    "handbook": {
        "toc": true
    },
    "incidents/incidents": {
        "toc": true
    }
}
```

This works fine for `handbook.md` located in the root directory, but `incidents.md` located in the directory `incidents` is not matched. I tried to have a bare "`incidents`" in `_data.json`, but it is not matched either.

**How should I reference `/incidents/incidents.md` in `_data.json`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `_data.json` file in the `incidents/` directory too. That’s where you’ll specify all the metadata for the pages in that folder:

```
{
  "incidents": {
    "toc": true
  }
}
```

Then `/incidents/incidents` will have the `toc` variable, too.